# graphics.h in CodeLite?

Tags: c++, c, codelite, bgi

> It was a header that was available in old Borland compilers. Used
>   strictly for graphics in MS-Dos apps. You are at least 7 operating
>   systems, 16 bits, 20 years and untold compiler versions removed from
>   using it.

Yes, I know that `<graphics.h>` is gone. I am new to C/C++ and my knowledge is confined to the computer graphics being taught to us in college.

Is there some way I can use `graphics.h` in `CodeLite` to study the programs?

Comment: Suggestion: Try something like OpenGL or Qt. They are definitely not so hard as you've imagined. :)

Comment: @starrify Well, okay how hard is it to try Bresenham and such in OpenGL?

Comment: `OpenGL` is an API collection, which provides graphics related primitives like drawing a point/line/polygon. It's supposed that if you're able to implement Bresenham using `graphics.h`, you'll find it easy to do it with `OpenGL`.

Comment: Try being new to *only* one of C or C++. The modern languages are very different, and it is best to focus on one.

Comment: Agreed with @crashmstr. They're different languages, although they have many in common.

Comment: Nowdays (graphic) libraries are not parts of IDE. So your question has nothing to do with CodeLite. You can use any library with any IDE.

Comment: if you are talking about [this header](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/materials/cppdoc/graphics.html) then the closest thing to it that I know in C++ is the Qt [`QPainter` class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainter.html). It should be reasonably easy to either re-write the code to use it directly or implement your own `graphics.cpp` that uses `QPainter`. I know Qt is overkill here but it's the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The similar level of abstraction in C can be easily reached with [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)
You will want [SDL_Surface](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface) to put points of Bresenham to.

I'd also recommend [ClanLib](http://clanlib.org/) for use with C++, as more convenient to start with.

Both libraries are cross-platform (and can use OpenGL as engine)

Answer (score 2):

The header file mentioned in your post is part of [Borland's Graphic Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Graphics_Interface) library and is most commonly associated with Turbo C++. Because of its age it is no longer officially supported by Borland. There are however alternatives like [OpenBGI](http://openbgi.sourceforge.net/) and [WinBGI](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/) which strive to emulate the functionality of the original library on modern systems. The source code for both libraries is available as well and are usable in CodeLite projects.

As a side note the [documentation](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/) is also available online.